# Django models column behaviour

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I added a column to a model. Then I accidentally deleted some migrations and did some random stuff. I got make migrations to work again but a column which I had deleted the migration file for is still in my database. I can't get rid of it.

My model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    campaignType = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="FC")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    url = models.TextField()
```

The database still has a column called imageUrl which I don't have in the model anymore. If I try adding imageUrl again it says duplicate column.

Comment: Remove the column manually.

Comment: @Shadow: that will solve the problem locally, but depending on how the issue was fixed with the migrations, it can arise when setting up a new database (for example on production).

Answer (score 0):

Try after deleting all migrations and pycache folders from your app.